# why does this knockout method receive a form element instead of the object its nested in?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have this HTML:

```
<ul class="chat_list" data-bind="foreach: chats">
  <li>
    <div class="chat_response" data-bind="visible: CommentList().length == 0">
      <form data-bind="submit: $root.addComment">
        <input class="comment_field" placeholder="Comment…" 
          data-bind="value: NewCommentText" 
        />
      </form>
    </div>            
  </li>
</ul>
```

and this JavaScript:

```
function ChatListViewModel(chats) {

   // var self = this;

    self.chats = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(chats, function (chat) {
        return { CourseItemDescription: chat.CourseItemDescription,
            CommentList: ko.observableArray(chat.CommentList),
            CourseItemID: chat.CourseItemID,
            UserName: chat.UserName,
            ChatGroupNumber: chat.ChatGroupNumber,
            ChatCount: chat.ChatCount,
            NewCommentText: ko.observable("")
        };
    }));

    self.newChatText = ko.observable();

    self.addComment = function (chat) {
        var newComment = { CourseItemDescription: chat.NewCommentText(),
            ParentCourseItemID: chat.CourseItemID,
            CourseID: $.CourseLogic.dataitem.CourseID,
            AccountID: $.CourseLogic.dataitem.AccountID,
            SystemObjectID: $.CourseLogic.dataitem.CommentSystemObjectID,
            SystemObjectName: "Comments",
            UserName: chat.UserName
        };
        chat.CommentList.push(newComment);
        chat.NewCommentText("");
    };
}
ko.applyBindings(new ChatListViewModel(initialData));
```

When I go into the debugger it shows that the `chat` parameter of the `addComment()` function is a form element instead of a chat object.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of KO behavior. To pass chat variable to submit handler you may use this:

```
<ul class="chat_list" data-bind="foreach: chats">
    <li>
        <div class="chat_response" data-bind="visible: CommentList().length == 0">
            <form data-bind="submit: function(form){$root.addComment($data, form)}">
                <input class="comment_field" placeholder="Comment…" data-bind="value: NewCommentText" />
            </form>
        </div>            
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand it. Why `function(form){....}` instead of just `$root.addComment($data, form)`

Comment: @ladookie - By default knockout is going to call whatever function you pass it with a single parameter, the form element. If you want to pass in more parameters you have to provide knockout with the one it expects, and then call the function you want with the additional parameters.

Answer (score 5):

This is by design. From the [Knockout.js docs](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html):

> As illustrated in this example, KO passes the form element as a
>   parameter to your submit handler function. You can ignore that
>   parameter if you want, but for an example of when it’s useful to have
>   a reference to that element, see the docs for the [ko.postJson utility](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/post-json.html).

As noted by [Serjio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11303901/11702) you can use currying to pass additional parameters into the function, or you can make use of [Knockout's Unobtrusive Event Handling](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html), which allows you to get the entire context associated with the form element.

```
self.addComment = function (form) {
    var context = ko.contextFor(form);
    var chat = context.$data;

    //rest of your method here
};
```

Comment: Is there a way to get a chat object while using a form?

Comment: a click handler would certainly be a better options if that is what you are going for.

Comment: Its nice to use a form because the user can just hit enter instead of having to click a button.

Comment: This is true, I just wasn't sure what user experience you were after. In that case I would go with Serjio's solution, or make use of Knockout's `ko.dataFor`, or `ko.contextFor` utility methods. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html